# Why are there borders in my clipped images in firefox and not chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So for some reason I have a per tile border* around my tiles** in  FireFox, but not in Chrome. Can anyone tell me how to fix this in Firefox without it effecting Chrome?

Each tile has a dark blue border around it in firefox when it should be a pure blue image.

Tiles are cropped from a tilesheet, and placed on the canvas.

http://jsfiddle.net/9YLmh/

```
    var canvasWidth = 800;
var canvasHeight = 600;

var tilemap;

var tilemapImg = new Image();
tilemapImg.src = 'lsf-sheet-1.png';

function Tilemap(){
        this.height = 5;
        this.width = 5;
        this.sheetWidth = 4;
        this.sheetHeight = 3;
        this.tile = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
        this.tileSize = 16;


        this.ready = true;
}

function drawCanvas(){
    var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d"); //get context of canvas

    if(tilemap.ready){
        for(var i = 0; i < (tilemap.height * tilemap.width); i++){
            var tempTile = tilemap.tile[i];
            var tempNum = i;
            var tempHeight = 0;

            var cx = (tilemap.tile[i] % tilemap.sheetWidth) * tilemap.tileSize;
            var cy = 0;
            while(tempTile >= tilemap.sheetWidth){
                tempTile -= tilemap.sheetWidth;
                cy += tilemap.tileSize;
            }

            while(tempNum >= tilemap.width){
                tempNum -= tilemap.width;
                tempHeight++;
            }

            var tileX = ((i % tilemap.width) * tilemap.tileSize);

            if((tileX + scrollX) >= -tilemap.tileSize && (tileX + scrollX) <= scrollX + canvasWidth){
                ctx.drawImage(tilemapImg, 
                    cx, 
                    cy, 
                    tilemap.tileSize, 
                    tilemap.tileSize, 
                    tileX + scrollX,
                    tempHeight * tilemap.tileSize,
                    tilemap.tileSize, 
                    tilemap.tileSize
                );
            }
        }
    }
}

function init() {
    var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d"); //get context of canvas
    ctx.scale(2.0,2.0);

    tilemap = new Tilemap();

    setInterval(drawCanvas, 1000 / 60);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    init();
});
```

Comment: No border for me in FF (Aurora 27)... do you have hardware acceleration enabled?

Comment: I'm on FireFox 25.0, and How would I check if the HW Acceleration is enabled?

Comment: Okay, according to this page http://blog.mozilla.org/joe/2010/11/10/how-to-tell-if-youre-using-hardware-acceleration/ my HW acceleration is enabled, as I don't see the “GPU Accelerated Windows: 0/1.” message.

Comment: And if you [turn it off](http://lifehacker.com/disable-firefoxs-hardware-acceleration-to-fix-slowness-749344037) ?

Comment: seems to be fixed when I turn it off. Whats that mean? It's my graphics card?

Comment: I don't think it's your card. Firefox do have some issues with HW enabled canvas and it's a fairly young implementations which of course means issues are stacked up. It's not much you do about at this point but sit and wait for Mozilla to fix it. The problem is most likely related to the size of the canvas/transfer. You can try to get around that and you can also try to translate the canvas half pixel to see if it reduces the problem (`ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5)`).

Answer (score 0):

With test on FF 25.0, the problem is reappeared no mather whether the HW Acceleration is enabled or not. The follow is my solution method for solving this problem(without effecting Chrome):

replace the code:

```
if((tileX + scrollX) >= -tilemap.tileSize && (tileX + scrollX) <= scrollX + canvasWidth){
                ctx.drawImage(tilemapImg, 
                    cx, 
                    cy, 
                    tilemap.tileSize, 
                    tilemap.tileSize, 
                    tileX + scrollX,
                    tempHeight * tilemap.tileSize,
                    tilemap.tileSize, 
                    tilemap.tileSize
                );
            }
```

with:

```
if ((tileX + scrollX) >= -tilemap.tileSize && (tileX + scrollX) <= scrollX + canvasWidth) {
                ctx.save();
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(tileX + scrollX, tempHeight * tilemap.tileSize, tilemap.tileSize, tilemap.tileSize);
                ctx.clip();
                ctx.drawImage(tilemapImg, cx, cy, tilemap.tileSize, tilemap.tileSize, tileX + scrollX, tempHeight * tilemap.tileSize, tilemap.tileSize + 1, tilemap.tileSize + 1);
                ctx.restore();
            }
```

so, the problem is solved, and hope that will be helpful to you.

Comment: Thank you for your time and reply, but this is way too slow to use, also (Not shown in example) it only seems to work on the first tile of the sheet. The others will have borders around them still. here is a JSfiddle wuth other tiles being used as well. http://jsfiddle.net/9YLmh/2/

Answer (score 0):

Here is another more simple solution:

replace:

```
                    cx, 
                    cy, 
                    tilemap.tileSize, 
                    tilemap.tileSize,
```

with:

```
                    cx, 
                    cy, 
                    tilemap.tileSize-1, 
                    tilemap.tileSize-1,
```

then the borders disappear(http://jsfiddle.net/9YLmh/3/).

I found that the border is just the pixels on the image, not caused by canvas.